# What is a typical dress code for campus interviews on west coast state schools?

Tags: job-search, job, tenure-track, interview, academic-dress

The question says it all.

I am shortlisted for a campus interview at a state school in California. I was wondering about the dress code? Should I wear a suit or would it be too much?

**EDIT:** It's for CSU math position in Northern California.

Comment: Depends on the field.

Comment: Just wear what you think is aporopriate. The location of the school doesn't even matter. Sort of like saying wear a cowboy hat to an interview in Texas.

Comment: @SeanRoberson No. There are often regional differences within an industry in what is considered to be appropriate attire, and this includes academia.

Comment: Based on the username, I'm assuming the department is math, but it would be good to specify this as the answer would be very different if this was for a position at a business school.

Comment: University of California vs Cal State might make a bit of difference. A suit is never wrong.

Comment: I wouldn't say "a suit is never wrong". I showed up to an interview once in a suit (for a math postdoc, at a large private institution in a rural part of the Northeast US) and my interviewer said to me "after the guy we interviewed last week showed up in a suit, I meant to call you and say a suit is not necessary".

Comment: If it's in California than it must be a flip-flop, shorts, t-shirt, and don't forget the "hang loose" sign.

Comment: Given your last edit, wear a button-down shirt, tucked in, and a reasonable pair of pants with a belt. Tie is optional if you're a sharp enough dresser to feel comfortable wearing one. And wear shoes that don't look ridiculous with the above. A suit is definitely too much. Signed, a woman in mathematics on the West Coast. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a general rule of clothing, it's better to be overdressed than underdressed. In that spirit, I would err on the side of dressing a bit more formally than what you anticipate to be "normal" for interviews in your field.

In my interviews, I have seen candidates in the full range of clothing, from jeans and t-shirt all the way to a full suit and tie. Personally, I usually wore simple suit pants and shoes, a simple jacket, and either a long-sleeved shirt or a nice and well-ironed polo shirt. I usually combined a dark-ish suit with a more colorful, less formal, shirt.

That said, it probably does not matter much at all. As I said, I have seen people wear all kinds of clothes to their interview, and I have never seen a correlation with interview success one way or the other.

Answer (score 5):

I'm honestly just guessing here, but I'd think something along the lines of [Business Casual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_casual) or [Smart Casual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_casual). Both of those are ambiguous, of course, but I think you'd stand out in a suit.

Of course San Francisco is more formal than LA or Berkeley, but academics in most fields are pretty laid back. If the interview will be long and includes evening events, you might want to have a suit available.

Answer (score -3):

I believe the only correct answer is that you should call the admissions office of whatever program you're applying to and ask. Everything else is just guessing.

Comment: The tags say tenure track and job search so the admissions office is probably not going to be informative.

Comment: *facepalm* That's what I get for reading the questions too quickly.